# Border for Specific Sides SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have added the borders for all sides using code below in `SwiftUI`

```
Rectangle()
 .overlay(Rectangle()
 .fill(Color.white).padding(2))
 .foregroundColor(Color.red)
```

How to add a border for specific sides of `Rectangle`?

Comment: So, you use code but do not accept answers... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution in this case is to use explicitly specified edges to which padding is applied

```
Rectangle()
    .overlay(Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.white).padding([.leading, .trailing], 2))  // << here !!
    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
```